# os.environ does not contain HOST variable

Tags: linux, shell, posix

What could be the cause that os.environ does not contain the HOST environment variable under Linux, except I set it explicitly for the interpreter environment?

```
> echo $HOST; python -c 'import os; print "HOST" in os.environ'
bbox
False
> echo $HOST; HOST=$HOST python -c 'import os; print "HOST" in os.environ'
bbox
True
```

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestion to `export`, however, why are most of the other variables available, like `USER, PS1, LANG,...` without explicitly exporting them?

Comment: You could also use [os.uname](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.uname), e.g. `os.uname[1]`.

Comment: Those other variables are already exported.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but which process is exporting them, I have nothing of this sort in my shell startup files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that you've got a variable called `HOST` defined in your shell, but have not exported it.

Try this:

```
export HOST
```

Environment variables are not passed to child processes unless they have been exported this way.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a variable in a shell does not make it available to subprocesses; you must export the variable as well.

```
$ export HOST
$ python ...
```